# Python detecting EOF

Tags: python, eof

I'm trying to write an if statement that goes as such, while reading a csv file:

```
if row = [] or EOF:
    do stuff
```

I've searched online and couldn't find any way of doing this. Help?

Comment: what are you going to do at the end of the file?

Comment: Do you know if the last character of your file will always be `\n`?

Comment: I have an array that's being appended to in every line that isn't blank, then once it hits a blank line or the end of the file, it should print the array to an output

Comment: @TimPietzcker no, it isn't always \n... that's the problem I'm having

Comment: so keep going until you reach a blank line or the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        # line = line.strip(' \r\n') # to remove spaces and new line chars if needed
        if not line:
            do stuff
    do stuff
```

The above is sufficient.

To check if you are in the end of file you can also do:

```
import os
with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
   is_end = f.tell() == os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
```

but I think you do not need to.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've specified in the question... the "do stuff" bit won't execute unless there's a blank line, and I only want it to happen at blank lines and at the very end of the file - not in every line...

Comment: Shouldn't that at least be `if not line:`?

Comment: Yeap, and add do stuff o the end of the iteration to be executed when the eof is reached

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I fully understand you but to ignore empty lines I would use `if line.strip()`.

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            # append
        else:
            # do what you need
    # do last requirement
```